# Why is my SELECT statement unable to find a table alias in one of its subqueries?

Tags: sql, sqlite, subquery, alias

My current query is the following:

```
select course_id, sec_id
from (select course_id, sec_id, count(id) as enrollment
      from takes natural join section
      where semester ='Fall' and year = 2009
      group by course_id, sec_id
      ) as s_enrollment
where enrollment = (select max(enrollment) from s_enrollment);
```

Why does it say that no `s_enrollment` table is found even though I already have it in the `from` statement? I am assuming this error is caused by the reference to `s_enrollment` in the `where` clause.

Here are the schemas for the `takes` and `section` tables.

```
takes   CREATE TABLE takes
    (ID         varchar(5), 
     course_id      varchar(8),
     sec_id         varchar(8), 
     semester       varchar(6),
     year           numeric(4,0),
     grade              varchar(2),
     primary key (ID, course_id, sec_id, semester, year),
     foreign key (course_id,sec_id, semester, year) references section
        on delete cascade,
     foreign key (ID) references student
        on delete cascade
    )

section CREATE TABLE section
    (course_id      varchar(8), 
         sec_id         varchar(8),
     semester       varchar(6)
        check (semester in ('Fall', 'Winter', 'Spring', 'Summer')), 
     year           numeric(4,0) check (year > 1701 and year < 2100), 
     building       varchar(15),
     room_number        varchar(7),
     time_slot_id       varchar(4),
     primary key (course_id, sec_id, semester, year),
     foreign key (course_id) references course
        on delete cascade,
     foreign key (building, room_number) references classroom
        on delete set null
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

**s_enrollment** is a derived table alias, you can't use in on same select statement, but you can use it if its joined or in a subquery.

another way of getting what you want is to sort by enrollment, in here you can get the max value.

```
select course_id, sec_id, enrollment
from (select course_id, sec_id, count(id) as enrollment
      from takes natural join section
      where semester ='Fall' and year = 2009
      group by course_id, sec_id
      ) as s_enrollment
order by enrollment desc limit 1;
```

Comment: Ah! I just assumed that if I just alias the derived table, I would be able to use it in a different subquery.  So basically that derived table alias is just useless and I can't use it any where only when I do a subquery in that subquery ?

Answer (score 0):

Your select statement contains two subqueries. Each of these subqueries can't "see" outside of the parentheses it's contained in. So when the second subquery references `s_enrollment`, it says that `s_enrollment` can't be found because no table called `s_enrollement` is created within that subquery's set of parentheses—`s_enrollment` is only created as a result of the first subquery.

If I understand correctly the intent of your query, this should produce the result you want:

```sql
select course_id, sec_id
from takes natural join section
where semester ='Fall' and year = 2009
group by course_id, sec_id
order by count(id) desc limit 1
```

Comment: So where else can I use s_enrollment relation created from the first subquery ?

Comment: @nguuguiu You could only use it in the top query, not a different subquery. For example, if you were using your initial query and decided to add a join to it, you would need to change `select course_id, sec_id` to `select s_enrollment.course_id, s_enrollment_sec_id`.

Comment: Oh that makes sense now. One more question I want to ask tho. So let's say that that whole query is  a subquery from another "from" command can I still use it in the "select?